# How to put a limit on my divisor when looking for a prime number

Tags: python

```
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
prime = True

if number <= 1:
    prime = False
    divisor = 1

divisor = 2
while divisor < number and prime == True:
    if divisor == number:
        break

while divisor < number and prime == True:
    if (number > 1) % divisor == 0:
        prime = False
    elif number % divisor !=0:
        prime = True
        divisor = divisor + 1

if number == 1:
    divisor = divisor - 1
        
        
if prime == True:
    print(f"{number} is prime.")
elif prime == False:
    print(f"{number} is not prime.")
    print(f"{number} is divisible by {divisor}")
```

I am trying to write code to determine whether the input number is a prime number or not (not including 1). It works when I put in numbers like 8, but if I put in a number like 27, the while loop goes on forever and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Puts lots of print functions everywhere in your code, showing relevant values, so you can easily trace your code logic (and find the flaw in the logic). You may want to put an empty `input()` inside the while loops, so the output doesn't scroll miles off the screen. Or you can use a debugger; that takes a bit to learn to use it, but the skill can pay off later on.

Comment: Your first loop will never finish since you never increment `divisor`

Comment: `if (number > 1) % divisor == 0` is probably not what you meant: you're performing modulo arithmetic on the result of `number > 1`, which is always `True`, which is the equivalent of 1 as an integer. So you get `1 % divisor == 0`.

Comment: Notwithstanding the code errors already identified in earlier comments, your algorithm is seriously flawed. Try searching stack**overflow** for solutions of which there are many

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugger like 'python tutor' or 'thonny'.
Your problem is on line 9, you have to have a way to escape the loop otherwise it goes forever because 2 is smaller than 27 and the if statement never goes to be true. You don't set any increaser/decreaser.